# Assigning values to singleton's object

Tags: javascript

I got this sample code where I try to assign values to a singleton's object:

```
var myVariable; 

var mySingleton = ( function() {
    var INSTANCE;

    var single = {
        variable1 : null,
        variable2 : null, 
        variable3 : null,
        variableOptions : [ {
            variableOption1 : null,
            variableOption2 : null
        } ]
    };

    I meant like that:

return {
    getMySingleton : function() { return single },
    setMySingleton : function( singletonParameter ) { $.extend( single, singletonParameter ) },
    getSingletonOptions : function ( index ) { return single.variableOptions[index] },
    setSingletonOptions : function( index, OptionsSingleton ) { $.extend( single.variableOptions[index] , OptionsSingleton )    },
    getInstance : function() {
        if (!INSTANCE) {
            INSTANCE = this;                    
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
})();

$(function() {
    var idx = 0;

    myVariable = mySingleton.getInstance(); // new empty instance
    $.each( $('#list > li'), function() {
        myVariable.setSingletonOptions(idx, { 
                                            variableOption1 : $(this).find('[id*="variableOption1_"]').val(),
                                            variableOption2 : $(this).find('[id*="variableOption2_"]').val()
        });
        idx++;
    });
    myVariable.setMySingleton({
        variable1 : $(this).find('[id*="variable1_"]').val(),
        variable2 : $(this).find('[id*="variable2_"]').val(),
        variable2 : $(this).find('[id*="variable2_"]').val()
    });

    console.log( myVariable.getMySingleton() );
});
```

but when I debug to console.log I get variable contents as null... what I'd have missed? I thought it was about passing by value...

Cheers,
Luigi

Comment: Where is `myCurrentSingleton` defined?

Comment: Also, you've defined that `single` object in the anonymous function, but nothing ever refers to it.

Comment: I re-edited the post... sorry haven't wrote correctly the code as I was testing... I was referencing to "single" object inside singleton

Comment: I never understand why people make a `getInstance` method while JS allows you to return what you want out of a constructor. I'd rather use [this singleton implementation](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=LssN9VCE).